# How accurate is the respresentation of York/Jórvík in the manga Vinland Saga?

Tags: england, vikings

In the manga [Vinland Saga](http://www.anime-planet.com/manga/vinland-saga), the heroes arrive at "York".  Clearly, it should have been called [Jórvík](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_York) but let's forgive them that for now. Below is how the manga shows the city from the sky. Comparing this map to a current [map of York](http://www.visityork.org/information/maps-of-york.aspx), the resemblance is striking.

However, *how accurate is it for Jórvík?*

[image: Vinland saga arriving in York/Jórvík]

Answer (score 2):

Within the scope of artistic licence it seems to be fairly close to what Roman York is believed to have [looked like](http://www.historyofyork.org.uk/themes/roman/the-roman-fortress). Given that Vikings didn't have a reputation for being much in the way of civil engineers it's probably reasonable to assume that Jorvik had much the same layout as the Roman and subsequent Anglo-Saxon versions.

That being said, "accuracy" of city maps from the Dark Ages is going to be iffy at the best of times...

[image: Eboracum]